# Alert message with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css, html

I need to output alert message if `val = -1`, but the problem is that this message appears at the bottom of the page and this does not depend on the value of val.

```
if ($val == -1) 
        echo '
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#dialog:ui-dialog" ).dialog( "destroy" );
                $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        Ok: function() {
                            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        ';
    else { //...  }


<div id="dialog-message" title="Process failed.">
<p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-circle-check"
    style="float: left; margin: 0 7px 50px 0;"></span> Error message.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is outside of your if statement, meaning that it will always display. You need to use css to hide it and what I would also do, is only add the HTML for the dialog when you need to show it, i.e. within the if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide the div use css

```
#dialog-message{
 display:none;
}
```

For a better alert there is a nice plugin for Alert, Confirm & Prompt use that plugin

http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/archived/jquery-alerts/demo/

It's download page is here

http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/12/jquery-alert-dialogs/

Answer (score 1):

You can use **position** function to position the dialog:

[Link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/position/)

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with the good old fashioned alert() javascript function?  It should do the job just fine in this situation.